# Need to invoke ioctl(tty0_fd, KDSETMODE, KD_TEXT) upon abnormal termination

Tags: c, linux, framebuffer, termination

I am using the Linux framebuffer in my application, and setting `ioctl(tty0_fd, KDSETMODE, KD_GRAPHICS)` to prevent any cursor or text from being displayed by the underlying terminal, and then cleaning up upon normal program termination.

But remaining in `KD_GRAPHICS` mode upon *abnormal* termination is a Bad Thing since it leaves the system unresponsive, and I'm wondering how to address that condition.

Functions registered with `atexit()` are only invoked upon normal termination, so that won't help.  I could register my own handlers for any signals that can kill the application, but `SIGKILL` cannot be trapped.

How do windowing environments and other programs handle this situation?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to spawn a process that lives independently of your main process that acts as a kind of watchdog. When it detects that your process has exited, it restores the terminal mode.